# Debian Package Manager broken

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I am an Elementary OS (Ubuntu) user, for a while now when I try to install something (`sudo apt-get install [...]`) I get the Unmet dependencies error, I type `sudo apt --fix-broken install` and I got another error back:

> Fixing Sub-process `/usr/bin/dpkg` returned an error code (1)

This error should be resolved by `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and I have a dependency error:

> dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of `kaccounts-integration`: Package `signond` is not installed. [...]

So I do `sudo apt-get install signond | sudo apt-get install kaccounts-integration` and in both I get the error:

> Fixing Sub-process `/usr/bin/dpkg` returned an error code (1)

If I do `sudo apt-get install -f`

> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
> Correcting dependencies... Done
> The following additional packages will be installed:
> signond
> The following NEW packages will be installed:
> signond
> 0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 54 not upgraded.
> 3 not fully installed or removed.
> Need to get 0 B/166 kB of archives.
> After this operation, 616 kB of additional disk space will be used.
> Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
> (Reading database ... 306231 files and directories currently installed.)
> Preparing to unpack .../signond_8.60+r699+dbusapi1+pkg3~daily~ubuntu5.1.2.1_amd64.deb ...
> Unpacking signond (8.60+r699+dbusapi1+pkg3~daily~ubuntu5.1.2.1) ...
> dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/signond_8.60+r699+dbusapi1+pkg3~daily~ubuntu5.1.2.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
> trying to overwrite '/usr/share/dbus-1/services/com.google.code.AccountsSSO.SingleSignOn.service', which is also in package gsignond 1.1.0~r509+pkg4~daily~ubuntu5.0.1
> Errors were encountered while processing:
> /var/cache/apt/archives/signond_8.60+r699+dbusapi1+pkg3~daily~ubuntu5.1.2.1_amd64.deb
> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: It gives me the error Fixing Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Does it return any other messages or just this single line?

Comment: I have edited the question so that you can see it, here the message does not fit

Comment: That's exactly what you're supposed to do. Thank you for _not_ trying to cram updates into comments

Comment: @Fox my bad, indeed (so I deleted my comment). I still think it's a packaging bug (each package should conflict with the other or the common part should be split in a 3rd -common package) but without knowing the tool at all I can't really know.

Comment: There are a number of articles on this around the w^3, maybe this one will help https://phoenixnap.com/kb/fix-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-error-code-1

Answer (score 3):

> dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/signond_8.60+r699+dbusapi1+pkg3~daily~ubuntu5.1.2.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
>
> trying to overwrite '/usr/share/dbus-1/services/com.google.code.AccountsSSO.SingleSignOn.service', **which is also in package gsignond** 1.1.0~r509+pkg4~daily~ubuntu5.0.1

Looks like you have two packages that want to own the same file (`signond` and `gsignond`).

`dpkg` will exit with an error in that situation unless you use its `--force-overwrite` option.

Try `apt-get -o Dpkg=force-overwrite -f install`.

Or add `DPkg { Options {"--force-overwrite";} };` to `/etc/apt/apt.conf` to make that the default behaviour for `apt` when it runs `dpkg` (worthwhile, IMO, because it's not uncommon for files to move from one package to another as the distro is updated).

Alternatively (or **additionally**), only have one of either `gsignond` or `signond` installed.